# Android context for LayoutInflater

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater

I have an activity with `ListView`.

Adapter for this `ListView` I've created from `android.widget.BaseAdapter`:

```
public class SaleItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        SaleItem saleItem = saleItems.get(position);
        if (saleItem.getFolder()) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_folder_item, viewGroup);
            TextView nameFolder = view.findViewById(R.id.nameFolder);
            nameFolder.setText(saleItem.getName());
        } else {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_sale_item, viewGroup);
        }
        return view;
    }
```

The question is: What kind of context I have to use for LayoutInflater?

I tried to use `getApplicationContext()` from my activity when instantiate adapter object `adapter = new SaleItemAdapter(this.getApplicationContext());` but it caused a crash on my application after this line of code:

```
view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_folder_item, viewGroup);
```

Comment: What does your stacktrace error say? I think the problem is in the way you get the Inflater.

Comment: How can I get stacktrace error in Android studio 3.1? Sorry for newbe question...

Comment: Open Logcat (shortcut alt + 6) on Android studio. If you have a device connected or emulator running it will show all the logs there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to initialize LayoutInflater like this

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

And them  inflate your view like this

```
view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
```

Comment: Question is where to find `context`?

Answer (score 0):

you have to create instance of `Context context` in Adapter class `constructor` then use this `context` for inflating layout check below code

```
        public class SaleItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  private Context context;

    ...
        public DischargeAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;

    }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            SaleItem saleItem = saleItems.get(position);
            if (saleItem.getFolder()) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_folder_item, viewGroup);
                TextView nameFolder = view.findViewById(R.id.nameFolder);
                nameFolder.setText(saleItem.getName());
            } else {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_sale_item, viewGroup);
            }
            return view;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**What kind of context I have to use for LayoutInflater?**

You have to pass main activity context. Try this,

Use:

**MainActivity**:

```
    adapter = new SaleItemAdapter(this);
```

**SaleItemAdapter**:

```
    view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_sale_item, null);
```

Instead of

**MainActivity**:

```
    adapter = new SaleItemAdapter(this.getApplicationContext());
```

**SaleItemAdapter**:

```
    view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_sale_item, viewGroup);
```

Your SaleItemAdapter should define a constructor,

```
   public class SaleItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private Context mContext;

    public SaleItemAdapter (Context context){
    mContext = context;
    }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    SaleItem saleItem = saleItems.get(position);
    if (saleItem.getFolder()) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_folder_item, null);
        TextView nameFolder = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameFolder);
        nameFolder.setText(saleItem.getName());
    } else {
        view = 
    LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_sale_item, null);
    }
    return view;
}
```